# Install graphiz on AWS Sagemaker

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-sagemaker

I'm on a Jupyter notebook using Python3 and trying to plot a tree with code like this:

```
import xgboost as xgb
from xgboost import plot_tree

plot_tree(model, num_trees=4)
```

On the last line I get:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'graphviz'
.........
.........
.........
~/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xgboost/plotting.py in to_graphviz(booster, fmap, num_trees, rankdir, yes_color, no_color, **kwargs)
196         from graphviz import Digraph
197     except ImportError:
--> 198         raise ImportError('You must install graphviz to plot tree')
199 
200     if not isinstance(booster, (Booster, XGBModel)):

ImportError: You must install graphviz to plot tree
```

How do I install graphviz so I can see the plot_tree?

Answer (score 4):

You can install and uninstall packages in your environment on notebook instance using following approach :-

- On your jupyter instance, go to the "Conda" tab. There you will find
  all the conda environments setup.
- Select your relevant environment. After you have selected your option, below in the right panel - you will see all the packages currently installed in your currently selected environment, and in the left panel - you will find what all packages are available and can be added into your environment.
- From the left panel, select "graphviz" and then install the selected package to your current environment.
- Restart the kernel using "Restart Kernel" option under "Kernel" in your notebook.

Alternatively, you may open a new terminal inside the Jupyterhub Notebook and then

1. Run `conda env list` to list all the available environments/kernels
2. Choose the one you wish to use (e.g. python3) and run `source activate python3`
3. Now run the desired `pip install ...` command
4. Once this is succeeded. Run `source deactivate` to close the env. And open up the notebook with the kernel and try import the model just installed.

Comment: Can you put your answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55112494/install-graphiz-on-aws-sagemaker

Comment: This question was migrated over from a different site and thus duped the one I had already but on here. Once you migrate your answer over I will remove this one.

Comment: I have successfully run PyTorch/graphviz from a notebook instance in SageMaker by installing pip torchviz. The SageMaker kernel already has graphviz-0.20.1 so it went smoothly. However, when I use Sagemaker Studio I get a `failed to execute PosixPath('dot'), make sure the Graphviz executables are on your systems' PATH` error. Somehow the studio version is different. What do you recommend?