# Install graphiz on AWS Sagemaker

Tags: xgboost, amazon-sagemaker

I'm on a Jupyter notebook using Python3 and trying to plot a tree with code like this:

```
import xgboost as xgb
from xgboost import plot_tree

plot_tree(model, num_trees=4)
```

On the last line I get:

```
~/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xgboost/plotting.py in to_graphviz(booster, fmap, num_trees, rankdir, yes_color, no_color, **kwargs)
196         from graphviz import Digraph
197     except ImportError:
--> 198         raise ImportError('You must install graphviz to plot tree')
199 
200     if not isinstance(booster, (Booster, XGBModel)):

ImportError: You must install graphviz to plot tree
```

How do I install graphviz so I can see the plot_tree?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was finally able to learn that Conda has a package which can install it for you. I was able to get it installed by running the command:

```
!conda install python-graphviz --yes
```

Note the `--yes` is only needed if the installation needs to verify adding/changing other packages since the Jupyter notebook is not interactive once it is running.

Comment: this isn't working for me presently.